# fetching particular value after applying string manupulation in url

Tags: php, regex

I am working on query string pattern for a redirection application. Can we use multiple `OR` statement in `strstr`. ex. if i am not sure whether it will be `& or & or $ or /` then is it possible to use the other signs in `OR` condition with `$code= strstr($code, '/',+1);`

Explanation:

the url will come to our redirect application like this

```
 https://www.sample.com?key=1234~rety~1234~retu&c=12&k=12
    OR
    https://www.sample.com?key=1234~rety~1234~retu/c=12/k=12
    OR
    https://www.sample.com?key=1234~rety~1234~retu$c=12$k=12
```

the only variable for our purpose is key(whose name can be changed but data will come int he same pattern) all i want is to get data with ~ pattern.

I am doing following:

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $parts);
$keys = array_keys($parts);
 $size=sizeof($keys);
$total=substr_count($uri, '~');
$var=$keys[0];
 $value=$parts[$var];   
 for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
     $var=$keys[$i];
     $value=$parts[$var];
     $total=substr_count($value, '~');
     if($total==3){
         $digit_code = preg_split('/\~+/', $value);
$digit_code = array_filter($digit_code);
$digit_code = array_values($digit_code);

$project_id=$digit_code[0];
$country_id=$digit_code[1];
$vendor=$digit_code[2];
$code=$digit_code[3];
//$code= strstr($code, '/',+1);
     }
```

But it is not working when url is coming like  this

```
https://www.sample.com?key=1234~rety~1234~retu/c=12/k=12
or
https://www.sample.com?key=1234~rety~1234~retu$c=12$k=12
```

Comment: Have you read `strstr` manual?

Comment: Yes i have gone through the manual. i am trying to find out some way to work around

Answer (score 0):

This is where using regex could be applicable:

```
preg_match('/((?:\/|&|\$).*)/', $code, $matches);
$code = $matches[1];
```

This will match a / or & or $ followed by the rest of the string.

https://www.php.net/preg_match

Answer (score 0):

are you referring in **PHP redirection**? or a **query string** in database to fetch data?

you can read `strstr` manual.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I just put

```
 if (strpos($code,'/') !== false) {
     $code= strstr($code, '/',+1);
}
  if (strpos($code,'$') !== false) {
     $code= strstr($code, '$',+1);
}
```

once after for loop